# Simple ? JSON analyse with AutoIt

Tags: json, autoit

I would like to use the following JSON which I read out from an API in AutoIt:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2336916545,
    "item_id": 85016,
    "price": 103,
    "quantity": 250,
    "created": "2020-06-07T18:13:46+00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2336916458,
    "item_id": 85016,
    "price": 103,
    "quantity": 250,
    "created": "2020-06-07T18:13:34+00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2336916352,
    "item_id": 85016,
    "price": 103,
    "quantity": 250,
    "created": "2020-06-07T18:13:22+00:00"
  }
]
```

What is the easiest way to multiply "price" and "quantity" and get a total sum for the array?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you update your question to show what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ward's work and its library [JSON.au3](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148114-a-non-strict-json-udf-jsmn/) to deal with JSON file.

### Install AGS-wrapper-json

To add easyly this library in your AutoIt project, you can use the package AGS-wrapper-json : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@autoit-gui-skeleton/ags-wrapper-json. An AGS-wrapper is a simple wrapper for an another library created by another team/developer integrated in [AGS framework](https://autoit-gui-skeleton.github.io/). More information about [dependency manager for AutoIt in AGS](https://autoit-gui-skeleton.github.io/2018/07/10/ags_dependencies_manager_for_AutoIt.html)

To install it :

```
λ  yarn add @autoit-gui-skeleton/ags-wrapper-json --modules-folder vendor
```

Finally to use this library in your AutoIt program, you need to include this library in the main program. There is no need for additional configuration to use it.

```
#include './vendor/@autoit-gui-skeleton/ags-wrapper-json/JSON.au3'
```

### Decode a JSON file from local

According to Ward's documentation.

> The most JSON data type will be decoded into corresponding AutoIt variable, including 1D array, string, number, true, false, and null. JSON object will be decoded into "Windows Scripting Dictionary Object" retuned from ObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary"). AutoIt build-in functions like IsArray, IsBool, etc. can be used to check the returned data type. But for Object and Null, Json_IsObject() and Json_IsNull() should be used.
>
> If the input JSON string is invalid, @Error will be set to $JSMN_ERROR_INVAL. And if the input JSON string is not finish, @Error will be set to $JSMN_ERROR_PART.

```
;====================================================================================
; Decode JSON from a given local file
;
; @param $jsonfilePath (string)
; @return $object (object), instance return by json_decode
;====================================================================================
Func json_decode_from_file($filePath)
    Local $fileOpen, $fileContent, $object
 
    $fileOpen = FileOpen($filePath, $FO_READ)
    If $fileOpen = -1 Then
        Return SetError(1, 0, "An error occurred when reading the file " & $filePath)
    EndIf
    $fileContent = FileRead($fileOpen)
    FileClose($fileOpen)
    $object = Json_Decode($fileContent)
 
    Return $object
EndFunc
```

### Get values from a json object

To work with $jsonObject, the return of json_decode_from_file, you can use Json_Get function. To select a JSON variable, both dot notation and square bracket notation can be supported.

For example :

```
Local $file = @ScriptDir & "\assets\DROIDS.json"
Local $jsonObject = json_decode_from_file($file)
 
; With dot notation
Local $project = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.project')     ; Listing droids
Local $name = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.author.name')    ; Luke
Local $mail = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.author.mail')    ; luke@2080.org
local $test = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.droids[1].name') ; BB8
 
; With array notation
Local $project2 = Json_Get($jsonObject, '["project"]')
Local $name2 = Json_Get($jsonObject, '["author"]["name"]')
Local $mail2 = Json_Get($jsonObject, '["author"]["mail"]')
local $test2 = Json_Get($jsonObject, '["droids"][1]["name"]')
```

### Work with an object collection, and iterate its items

To iterate values from an array json

```
Local $file = @ScriptDir & "\assets\DROIDS.json"
Local $jsonObject = json_decode_from_file($file)
 
; Check if exists an item droid into the collection `droids`
Local $droids = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.droids')
If UBound($droids) = 0 Then
    Return SetError(3, 0, "Array attribute 'droids' is empty.")
EndIf
 
; Iterate items collection to store values into an array
Local $array[UBound($droids)][3]
For $i = 0 To UBound($droids) - 1 Step 1
    $array[$i][0] = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.droids' & '[' & $i & '].name')
    $array[$i][1] = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.droids' & '[' & $i & '].type')
    $array[$i][2] = Json_Get($jsonObject, '.droids' & '[' & $i & '].size')
Next
```

Comment: For multiplication ... I have no idea :p

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test this and give you more information when it's done :)